# Width of different elements in Xaml

Tags: xaml, grid, width, stackpanel

I have a grid with two columns with width 3* and 1*. Inside the first column i have a stack panel with "width="Auto"" and with different grids inside it with vertical orientation. The grids have two columns with 15* and 1*.

So my question is how to set the first column of the first grid to adjust to the size of the screen and the second column to be always static lets say 50p? i've trayed to set auto to the first column and its elements but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinitions Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: ok thanks and how to set the width of the stack panel's grids to occupy the width of the main grid?

Comment: set the horizontalalignment of the stackpanel to stretch

Comment: no problwm, you're welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as the answer ;)